# perl regex selectively replace the record separator

Tags: regex, perl

I have a CSV file having patterns the below pattern

```
(rupert, paul, 23, 8, [{fin, dan, jack},{bill,34,26,49},{84,28}],{34,jack,bon})
```

The CSV with in the "{}" and "[]" should be replaced with a pipe character "|". The formatted output should be as below.

```
(rupert, paul, 23, 8, [{fin| dan| jack}|{bill|34|26|49}|{84|28}],{34|jack|bon})
```

I want to use a Perl regex but am getting nowhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The solution provided by the perl guru's work fine for single {} however i found that the free flowing text has some nested {}'s. I tried modifying the perl onliner's to accommodate the nested flower braces with no success.

(1,2,der,bet,na,4,5,{a,b,1,2,sd[{1,2},{4,5}],c{q,ew,3,4},1,2,3,cf{2,4,5,8},6}.

The solution gives

(1,2,der,bet,na,4,5,{a,b,1,2,sd[{1|2},{4|5}],c{q|ew|3|4},1,2,3,cf{2|4|5|8}|6}.

But the need is to have

(1,2,der,bet,na,4,5,{a|b|1|2|sd[{1|2}|{4|5}]|c{q|ew|3|4}|1|2|3|cf{2|4|5|8}|6}.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex that will check if the comma is followed by `]` or `}` with no preceding them.

```
my $s = "(rupert, paul, 23, 8, [{fin, dan, jack},{bill,34,26,49},{84,28}],{34,jack,bon})\n(rupert, paul, 23, 8, [{fin| dan| jack}|{bill|34|26|49}|{84|28}],{34|jack|bon})"; 
$s =~ s/,(?=(?:\{[^{}]*\}|[^{}])*})|,(?=(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*\])/|/g;
print "$s\n";
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/kXAoaP)

And here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY0aD0/3)

Comment: Just accepting the answer is really enough. There are a lot of other good regex testing Web sites (e.g. [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/)), too.

Comment: Please ley me know if you need more assistance with it.

Comment: Thank you, i tried changing the regex so that the pattern matches replaced the complete structure. For example (1,2,3,4,{1,1,1,3[{a,b,c},{a,b,c}],4,5[{d,c,e},{d,c,e}],5},4 gives me (1,2,3,4,{1,1,1,3[{a|b|c}|{a|b|c}],4,5[{d|c|e}|{d|c|e}]|5},4. I need (1,2,3,4,{1|1|1|3[{a|b|c}|{a|b|c}]|4|5[{d|c|e}|{d|c|e}]|5},4. Great if this is possible in a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

You can just go over the string character by character, remembering how deep you are in brackets, and replace commas with vertical bars if needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = '(rupert, paul, 23, 8, [{fin, dan, jack},{bill,34,26,49},{84,28}],{34,jack,bon})';

my $inside;
for my $pos (0 .. length($string) - 1) {
    my $char = substr $string, $pos, 1;
    $inside++ if $char =~ /[[{]/;
    $inside-- if $char =~ /[]}]/;
    substr $string, $pos, 1, '|' if ',' eq $char && $inside;
}
print $string, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
,(?=[^\[{}]*(?:\]|}))
```

You can try this and replace by `|`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/3